# reload a parent div from colorbox

Tags: jquery, html, parent, colorbox, reload

I have a colorbox iframe with a shopping-cart. I need to reload a parent div that shows a "shopping-cart monitor", because I have a "empty cart" link on that colorbox iframe.

```
            $("#submit<%response.write productid%>").click(function(event) {
            alert('actualizo carromonitor!');
            parent.$("#carromonitor").html.load("carromonitor.asp");
            });
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a mistake in this line:

```
parent.$("#carromonitor").html.load("carromonitor.asp");
```

The html() function in jquery should look like this:

```
parent.$("#carromonitor").html("Your HTML code here");
```

However, since you want to load it via ajax, you don't need the html() function.  You can do it this way:

```
parent.$("#carromonitor").load("carromonitor.asp");
```

Also, your code in the iframe document itself needs to be in a document ready block.  You didn't mention it, so I don't know if you've already done that, but it shouldn't run before the iframe is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit<%response.write productid%>").click(function(event) {
        alert('actualizo carromonitor!');           
        parent.$("#carromonitor").load("carromonitor.asp");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Jack - the +200 very much appreciated.  And glad I could give a little back.  Thanks again for your excellent work

Comment: Sorry, my thanks coming a lot of days later. It worked perfect! Thanks @DonamitelsTnt!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Would this do it:

```
$("#submit<%response.write productid%>").click(function(event) {
  alert('actualizo carromonitor!');
  $("#carromonitor").load("carromonitor.asp");
});
```

Since `#carromonitor` is an ID and should therefore be unique, the fact that it's related to the clicked element shouldn't matter. If you are duplicating IDs (which you shouldn't be), replace `$('#carromonitor')` with `$(this).closest('#carromonitor')`

One issue you might run into is that the click handler is not called after the first time (assuming that the #submitXXX element is inside #carromonitor). In that case, replace:

```
$("#submit<%response.write productid%>").click(function(event) {
```

with

```
$("#submit<%response.write productid%>").live('click', function(event) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Your first suggestion was already tried, but no results.
('#carromonitor') is unique... is loaded into a DIV on parent page, and reloaded every time the customer buys a product on the same page.

That works fine. But cannot do the same into colorbox.

('#submitXXX') is into the colorbox, not in $('#carromonitor').

And ('#carromonitor') doesn`t reload with #submitXXX "buying clicks".